Some options are not beeing displayed
In my HTML I have created a select tag and I want to add options dinamically.
<select class="form-control selectpicker"
data-style="btn btn-outline"
id="mySelect"
data-live-search="true"
>
   <option class="d-none" value="all" selected>My option</option>
</select>

I have to read the keys and values from a json and then create the options. There are around 2000 keys in the file.
const mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  fetch("myFile.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      Object.entries(result).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = value;
        option.text = key;
        mySelect.appendChild(option);
      });
      $(mySelect).selectpicker("refresh");
    });

Only around 100 options are beeing created. But if I make a console.log inside the loop I get all keys. How is it possible? Am I doing something wrong?

Change value of elem.value and elem.text, and you should assign elem.value to the key and elem.text to the value.
Try this code:
const mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
fetch("myFile.json")
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((result) => {
Object.entries(result).forEach(([key, value]) => {
const elem = document.createElement("option");
elem.value = key; // Set value to the key
elem.text = value; // Set text to the value
mySelect.appendChild(elem);
});
$(mySelect).selectpicker("refresh");
});

The value must be the value and the text must be the key. Thats not the problem.

I just found the issue and It is about the selectpicker. There is a default config parameter called virtualScroll that limit the number of options to be rendered.
$.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.DEFAULTS.virtualScroll = myLimit;


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
